# back/lays values just like on betfair site

Tags: php, algorithm, betfair

while working on betfair api getMarketPricesCompressed and getMarketPrices return the real price and real amount of money for each odd in the market but not the virtual values showed by betfair.

Have someone written such algorithm in php to calculate virtual values shown on betfair wesite.

Betfair did not provided the code or algorithm but this link only http://bdp.betfair.com/index.php?opt...=237&Itemid=62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BfPy - Betfair Python library](http://code.google.com/p/bfpy/) has an implementation of the algorithm

http://code.google.com/p/bfpy/source/browse/src/bfpy/bfvirtual.py

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by virtual values?? 
The prices on the site can be a little slow due to the medium they are delivered in 
(I.E. HTML) 
If you refer to the S.P. this is how it is calculated 
http://www.betfair.com/help/Help.SP.Betting/